# Springboot application does not join coherence cluster while connected to the network via VPN

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, oracle-coherence

I have a J2EE webapp running on oracle weblogic server and uses oracle coherence cache. There are a few springboot microservices running parallel and leverages coherence. When connected to the network via VPN, the springboot application fails to join the coherence cluster. Works perfectly fine while not using VPN.

I tried out the solution provided in the question below, but no success so far.

[Not able to connect coherence cluster from web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229240/not-able-to-connect-coherence-cluster-from-web-application)

Operational override xml:

```
<cluster-config>
    <member-identity>
     <cluster-name system-property="tangosol.coherence.cluster">XXXXXX</cluster-name>
  </member-identity>
   <unicast-listener>
  <socket-provider system-property="tangosol.coherence.socketprovider"/>
  <reliable-transport system-property="tangosol.coherence.transport.reliable"/>
  <well-known-addresses>
    <socket-address id="1">
      <address system-property="tangosol.coherence.wka">localhost</address>
      <port system-property="tangosol.coherence.wka.port">10000</port>
    </socket-address>
  </well-known-addresses>
  <address system-property="tangosol.coherence.localhost">localhost</address>
  <port system-property="tangosol.coherence.localport">10000</port>
  <port-auto-adjust system-property="tangosol.coherence.localport.adjust">true</port-auto-adjust>
  <priority>10</priority>
</unicast-listener>

    <multicast-listener>
        <time-to-live system-property="tangosol.coherence.ttl">4</time-to-live>
        <join-timeout-milliseconds>3000</join-timeout-milliseconds>
    </multicast-listener>
</cluster-config>
<configurable-cache-factory-config>
    .......
</configurable-cache-factory-config>>
```

The following message is printed in the console.

2019-08-05 10:15:15.616/24.238 Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.3.0.0  (thread=localhost-startStop-1, member=n/a): TCMP bound to /192.168.1.101:10002 using SystemDatagramSocketProvider
2019-08-05 10:15:46.542/55.164 Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.3.0.0  (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): This Member(Id=0, Timestamp=2019-08-05 10:15:15.65, Address=XXX.XXX.X.XXX:10002, MachineId=34270, Location=site:,machine:XXXXXXX,process:34700, Role=XXXXXX) has been attempting to join the cluster using WKA list [/XXX.XXX.X.XXX:10000] for 30 seconds without success; this could indicate a mis-configured WKA, or it may simply be the result of a busy cluster or active failover.
2019-08-05 10:15:46.542/55.164 Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.3.0.0  (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): Delaying formation of a new cluster; waiting for well-known nodes to respond

Something that popped up while hunting for solution is the fact that localhost doesn't resolve while connected via VPN. If this was the case, I don't understand why is the webapp (http://localhost:7001) loading in the browser without any issues. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the communication method of the cluster: multicast or unicast.
After you have to check if the communication method selected is supported from the vpn network.